# Four equilateral triangles' areas sum to a fith

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Let's have five equilateral triangles. From these five triangles one has an area equal to the sum of the other four triangles. All triangles have heights which are rational numbers. Can you find five such equilateral triangles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a picture of my solution:

> [image: Triforce]

Let the height of a small triangle be 1. The large triangle has height 2.